# Errors in code for User defined class

Tags: java

I have two programs that are needed to be used. Grade.java and Gradeclient.java.
I am given the following for Grade.java.

```
public class Grade
{
  private char letterGrade;

  public Grade( char 1g )
  {
    letterGrade = 1g;
  }
  public char getLetterGrade()
  {
    return letterGrade;
  }
  publicvoid setLetterGrade( char 1g)
  {
    letterGrade = 1g;
  }
}
```

and I am told 'In the main method of class Grade client,

```
Grade g = new Grade( 'B');
g.letterGrade = 'A';
```

This shows an error of " lettergrade has private access in Grade ".

From what I understand, I am missing a mutator method to access grade. However, I am not exactly sure how I should code this and where to start.

This is what I have tried thus far:

```
public class GradeClient
{
    public static void main( String [] agrs )
  {

Grade g = new Grade( 'B' );
  g.letterGrade = 'A':

    }
}
```

In addition to this, the second part of this program has the following:

in the main method of the class GradeClient

```
Grade g = new Grade( "A" );
```

And compiling it creates the error " string cannot be converted to char.

I'm utterly confused on how to even start to create GradeClient.java as for from a previous example public string and public class, both are for accessor method and mutator method, but I'm unsure how they work.

Can someone explain to me how I should start GradeClient.java and the difference of public string and public class? In addition, what does it mean "In the main method of the class GradeClient", is that simply in the void main, or is it entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

In the main method of the class GradeClient means that you have to put

```
public static void main(String[] args) { }
```

Also, you have `g.letterGrade = 'A';` , use `g.setLetterGrade('A');`

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `letterGrade` as private for the `Grade` which means that it can only be directly accessed within `Grade`.

If you want to change the value of `letterGrade` after instantiation, then you can use your defined public method `setLetterGrade` like

```
g.setLetterGrade('A');
```

Regarding the compilation error "string cannot be converted to char", it's because in the line `Grade g = new Grade( "A" );` you used double quotes in the parameter to the constructor. Using double quotes means you are defining a `String`. However, in the constructor, you defined the parameter as `char`. If you want to use `char` as a parameter, then you should use single quotes when instantiating the `Grade`

```
Grade g = new Grade( 'A' );
```